# select first in group query

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Apologies if this has been answered previously.

Say I have the following table:

```
colA | colB | colC
-----|------|-----
a    | 1    | 9
a    | 2    | 8
b    | 1    | 4
b    | 2    | 3
b    | 1    | 3
c    | 5    | 1
c    | 4    | 2
```

and I want to select the first row from each group (of column a, when sorted by column b,c asc)

```
colA | colB | colC
-----|------|-----
a    | 1    | 9
b    | 1    | 3
c    | 4    | 2
```

What is the tidiest way to structure the query to get these results?

(Postgresql 9)

Thanks, P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) and a derived table:

```
select cola, colb, colc
from (
    select cola, colb, colc,
           rank() over (partition by cola order by colb, colc asc) as r
    from your_table
) as dt
where r = 1
```

Window functions are pretty handy and should be in everyone's SQL toolkit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i think my solution is "tidier" so unless you can convince me otherwise i'll give myself the tick (in a day or 2). if you don't agree, i would appreciate the debate!

(ps i have upvoted your answer all the same...)

Comment: i'm ticking yours because you are right, it is the more 'standard' approach, however in my case i'm going to use my solution. thx.

Answer (score 3):

Besides "mu is too short"'s answer using window functions (which a college also turned me on to) I found that i can achieve the functionality using the much simpler "distinct on" feature:

```
select distinct on (colA) * from tbl order by colA, colB, colC;
```

Comment: [DISTINCT ON](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-select-lists.html#QUERIES-DISTINCT) is a reasonable approach in this case. The only downside that comes to mind is that it is non-standard, I tend to prefer standards based solutions for future proofing.

Answer (score 0):

I used to have the same problem as you.I used a window function and a derived table then solve the problem.